# Questions about MTG rules and gameplay strategies for physical card games should not belong here

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, allowed-answers

Take games like *Magic the Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers*.

I feel questions on card rulings and/or gameplay strategies should belong on [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/), as they already carry a load of ruling and gameplay based questions about MTG.

Despite Duels of the Planeswalkers being a video game, it's really just a re-work of the cardgame. It is not a video game.

Comment: Duels of the Planeswalkers *is* a video game. Just because it's a recreation of a card game doesn't make it any less a video game. Would we not accept questions about Pong because it's just table tennis?

Comment: I'll agree with you on the card ruling bit. But asking how to unlock an achievement, or a strategy for a particular deck in the game, should still be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to agree. I think that we should answer any questions inherently about the video game portion, like how to unlock certain aspects of the game or how to get past certain pre-set encounters. We shouldn't, however, answer questions that could have the video game removed from them altogether.

Compare to countless video chess simulators. We could answer questions about the video game components of these, but we should not even attempt to answer questions about chess rules or strategy. The same should hold true for Magic the Gathering and other similar games.

Most of all, rather than a blanket ban of all Duels of the Planeswalkers questions, let's use some common sense when questions come up.

Comment: Additionally, the people over at BCG are _lightning fast_ with MtG answers.  It would be a service to the asker to migrate ruling questions there.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Well, BCG could just as well be renamed to "mtg-and-some-other-stuff.stackexchange"